# Why is window.localStorage empty when I can see the data in the debugger?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm storing some data in local storage, but having problem retrieving them when the page opens for the first time.

This is my code:

```
lib.getUserGeoLocation();
lib.getUserCityLocation();

var lib = {
    getUserGeoLocation: function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

        function onSuccess(position) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("latitude", position.coords.latitude);
            window.localStorage.setItem("longitude", position.coords.longitude);
        }

        function onError(error) {
            // (...)
        }

    },

    getUserCityLocation: function(){
        var lat = window.localStorage.getItem("latitude");
        var lng = window.localStorage.getItem("longitude");

    console.log(window.localStorage);
    }
}
```

The result is: `Storage {length: 0}`
But when I look in the debugger, the data is there:

[image]

Does anyone know why `window.localStorage` is zero / `window.localStorage.getItem("latitude")` returns null?

**Update**

I've also tried this solution to make sure I have the values before I call `getUserCityLocation()`:

```
$.when(lib.getUserGeoLocation()).then(function(){
    lib.getUserCityLocation();
});
```

**Solution**

So my solution is this:

```
getUserGeoLocation: function(callback){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    function onSuccess(position) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("latitude", position.coords.latitude);
        window.localStorage.setItem("longitude", position.coords.longitude);
        return callback(true);
    }

    function onError(error) {
        return callback(false, error);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because **getUserGeoLocation** will take some time to get the data and then insert values in **localStorage** and meanwhile you are calling the function **getUserCityLocation**, so this will return you null.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that. While your answer might be an explanation, it's not a solution. I've tried using `$.when().then()` without success (see my updated Q). Any suggestions?

Comment: If you write getUserCityLocation in success function then it will work.

Comment: @Learning that wont be a proper solution. his scenario seems to be this "Whenever he used the function getUserCityLocation  he needs to get the location values", by using getUserCityLocation  inside success he is just getting the values on success but not when he needs it

Comment: Yeah, I added callback `getUserGeoLocation: function(callback)`and in `onSuccess() ` I just do `return callback(true);`

Answer (score 0):

"onSuccess" and "onError" are async calls which get called once the value is available where as getUserGeoLocation and getUserCityLocation are called one after another. So the code in getUserCityLocation is already called before onSuccess callback is called

When you use when and then, you should either return or call success or error of then from the when callback. Since getUserGeoLocation is not doing that you are still getting empty

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can I get `getUserGeoLocation()` to use callback to return geoposition?

Comment: I will update the code! Your issue wont be solved by then,when or deferred since your purpose is use getUserCityLocation () function and the get the values.